AGM Battery in a 1997 F-250 7.3 v8 diesel truck
Can you put AGM batteries into this truck? It has a standard lead acid charging system, and lead acid batteries are out of my budget, so I'm wondering if I could put AGM instead, or if the charging voltage would cause bad damage to the batteries. It takes two batteries.

Would you explain how AGM batteries can be within your budget if flooded lead acid batteries are out of your budget? AGM batteries are always more expensive than flooded lead acid batteries of the same CCA and AH.
